# Visual Studio: How do you allow a blank value or not having to select a value which defaults to an ALL?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I have a very basic SSRS report setup through Visual Studio. The parameters I have set do not have "Allow blank value","ALlow null value", and "Allow multiple values" as of now but I have tried using them with no luck. The allow blank value and allow null value do not seem to work at all.

In the preview, it still pops up with "Please select a value for the parameter 'xxxx'.

I have tried messing around with the "column = @column" vs "column IN @column" query in the main dataset query.
I have also searched google and set the extra dataset query to "select distinct column from table where column is not null"
I have also tried using a UNION in the query where it gives me the option to choose "NULL" as an option but the null doesn't include everything so the result gives me nothing....

Does anyone know a workaround or how to get a single parameter to have the option to not be required where it sets it as selecting all?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you all!

-EDIT
This is what I have as the query "SELECT DOCDATE, DOCID, CUSTNMBR, CUSTNAME, DOCAMNT FROM SOP30200 WHERE (DOCDATE BETWEEN @Fromdate AND @Todate) GROUP BY DOCDATE, DOCID, CUSTNMBR, CUSTNAME, DOCAMNT HAVING (CUSTNMBR = @Custnmbr OR @Custnmbr IS NULL) AND (DOCID IN (@DocID) OR @DocID IS NULL)" but I still cannot get the docID section to be blank. What that above, I still need a SP or something from your below example?

Comment: Change if my answer provided you with enough info please accept it.

Comment: You need to add the conditions in the where clause not the having statement `WHERE CUSTNMBR = @CUSTNMBR OR @CUSTNUMBR IS NULL`

Answer (score 2):

By setting allow null value you are stating that your dataset looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myRSStoredProcedure
 @MyParameter varchar(50)=NULL
 --more code
 SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (MyField=@MyParameter OR @MyParameter IS NULL)

END
```

That is that NULL is a valid value and is referenced somewhere in your stored procedure, noteice the part `WHERE (MyField=@MyParameter OR @MyParameter IS NULL)` this handles it for a value or for a NULL.  If you dont include the `OR @MyParameter IS NULL` and all you have is `WHERE MyField=@MyParameter` then how would you expect RS to "Allow Nulls" considering you are not addressing them.

For allow multiple values, this is only an indicator in Reporting Services that allows for multiple selections.  You would still have to handle the Comma Seperated Value in your dataset (your stored procedure), you cannot just say:

`SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID IN (@MyParam)`

It doesn't work that way.  A method to fix this would involve creating a table valued function that takes a CSV list and returns a table of integers say.  Here is an example:

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[CsvToInt] ( @Array varchar(1000)) 
returns @IntTable table 
    (IntValue int)
--Parse comma seperated value parameters
--To be used in SELECT blah WHERE blah IN (...)
--This function returns int, but may be modified to return any datatype
AS
begin

    declare @separator char(1)
    set @separator = ','

    declare @separator_position int 
    declare @array_value varchar(1000) 

    set @array = @array + ','

    while patindex('%,%' , @array) <> 0 
    begin

      select @separator_position =  patindex('%,%' , @array)
      select @array_value = left(@array, @separator_position - 1)

        Insert @IntTable
        Values (Cast(@array_value as int))

      select @array = stuff(@array, 1, @separator_position, '')
    end

    return
end
```

Finally, a slick way to include "All" data as opposed to an empty selection to mean give me all the data is to create two datasets.  The first dataset is your parameter, for instance for a Customer you may have:

```
SELECT
  1 As SortOrder
  CustomerID,
  Customer
FROM
  MyCustomers
UNION ALL
SELECT
  0 As SortOrder
  0 As CustomerID,
  'All' As Customer
ORDER BY
  SortOrder,
  Customer
```

This will list all customers with the word All at the top (notice SortOrder).
And then your RS report parameters you can specify the default value as 0 (if you are using the CustomerID) or `All` (if you are using the actual customer name).  Your report dataset would then do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rsp_MainReport
@CustomerID int = 0  --this could also be @CustomerID varchar(50)='All'
--more code
SELECT Blah FROM MyTable WHERE (CustomerID = @CustomerID OR @CustomerID=0) 
--or you could of done WHERE (Customer = @Customer OR @Customer='All')
```

I'll post an example I have done for you, heres a parameter dataset:

```
SELECT 
                    1 as SortOrder,
                    FacilityID,
                    Facility
                FROM
                    Facility
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    0 as SortOrder,
                    0 as FacilityID,
                    'All' as Facility
                ORDER BY 
                    SortOrder,
                    Facility
```

With the following result:

[image]

Then you can use that in your main dataset (the dataset for your report):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rsp_QuikFixStats_ByFacilityCategory
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @FacilityID bigint=0,
    @StartDate datetime=NULL,
    @EndDate datetime=NULL

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT 
        f.Facility,
        c.Category, 
        COUNT(t.TicketID) AS TotalNumberOfTickets,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ClosedDate IS NULL AND TargetDate IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalNumberOfOpenTickets,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ClosedDate IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalNumberOfClosedTickets,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TargetDate IS NULL AND ClosedDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalNumberOfWaitForTickets,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TargetDate IS NOT NULL AND ClosedDate IS NULL AND TargetDate < GetDate() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalNumberOfOverdueTickets
    FROM 
        Ticket t
    INNER JOIN
        Facility f
    ON
        f.FacilityID = t.FacilityID
    INNER JOIN
        Category c
    ON
        c.CategoryID = t.CategoryID
    WHERE 
        (f.Inactive=0)
        AND (f.FacilityID = @FacilityID OR @FacilityID=0)
        AND (t.OpenDate >= @StartDate OR @StartDate IS NULL)
        AND (t.OpenDate <= @EndDate OR @EndDate IS NULL)
    GROUP BY
        f.Facility,
        c.Category
    ORDER BY
        f.Facility,
        COUNT(t.TicketID) DESC,
        c.Category      
END
GO
```

The report parameters look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very quick response JonH. I am still fairly new to SQL. I only know how to query around. I do not know T-SQL or how to create stored procedures. What about the "Allow blank value" option? I tried using that and it doesn't work at all...still requires me to select a value.

Comment: @JaeChang - How will you create datasets without knowing stored procedures?  In this case you'd be creating table direct queries right within reporting services to display data.  Personally I don't recommend that...Even if you use direct tables your query can be `SELECT blah FROM MyTable WHERE MyField=@MyParam OR MyParam IS NULL`

Comment: Yes, I am using a direct query within Visual Studio Reporting(called reporting services?) to create my datasets. Is there a reason you don't recommend that?

Comment: I personally feel that the stored procedure layer allows for additional security as well as flexibility such as reusing the same stored procedure for different reports or even objects on that report.  Table direct becomes complex because you end up with a bunch of direct joins and data selection right from within RS.  I like to abstract that away to the database level.  All RS knows is that a stored procedure exists (sort of like a black box).